# SQL how to do an outer join properly

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table filled with the phone numbers of a company.
My problem is, we have a row for every number an employee have, so if he have a main phone and a mobile phone, we have two rows of him.

Now I need to show a list of all employees with their phone number and mobile number (if he have) and the email, but the email is in another table. 
Im using SQL.

An example:

PhoneTable

```
   ID  | EmpID  |  FullName     |  Number        |  Type     |
----------------------------------------------------------------
   115 |    02  |  ManuelSan    | +34935556663   |   Fix     |
   116 |    02  |  ManuelSan    | +34652315453   |   Mobile  |
   117 |    06  |  Camillete    | +34934445621   |   Fix     |
   118 |    07  |  MarcusEsq    | +34932547841   |   Fix     |
   119 |    08  |  FionaYem     | +34965214785   |   Fix     |
   120 |    08  |  FionaYem     | +34652132124   |   Mobile  |
```

EmailTable

```
    ID   |   empID   |   Fullname   |        Email           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   25    |    02     |  ManuelSan   |  Manuelsan@gg.com      |
   26    |    06     |  Camillete   |  Camillete@gg.com      |
   27    |    07     |  MarcusEsq   |  MarcusEsq@gg.com      |
   28    |    08     |  FionaYem    |  FionaYem@gg.com       |
```

So I want this output

```
   Fullname |    Fix       |     Mobile    |      Email  
------------------------------------------------------------------
 ManuelSan  | +34935556663 | +34652315453  |  Manuelsan@gg.com
 Camillete  | +34934445621 |      NULL     |  Camillete@gg.com
 MarcusEsq  | +34932547841 |      NULL     |  MarcusEsq@gg.com
 FionaYem   | +34965214785 | +34652132124  |  FionaYem@gg.com
```

But im doing this:

```
SELECT distinct telf.Fullname, telf.Number, acti.EMAIL
  FROM PhoneTable telf
  left outer join EmailTable as acti on acti.empID = telf.empID
```

I know I need to do something else but I dont know what. Im getting two rows per employee if him have a phone and a mobile.

How should I do that?

Regards,

Comment: Why do all email entries have the same ID? Why do you store the employee name in two tables? Dont you have an employee table? Can there be multiple emails for an employee? Can there be multiple fix numbers per employee? Can there be multiple mobile numbers per employee? What to do if I find different employee names for the same employee ID? What are the tables unique keys?

Comment: And does every employee have at least one phone? Does every employee have at least one email address?

Comment: Sorry about the same ID on the emailTable, just changed it.
And no, the phone can be null but the email address its mandatory.

Comment: That doesn't answer all questions. So the email table is the employee table actually? Exactly one email per employee? And there can be one or zero fix phone number and one or zero mobile phone number per employee?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of redundant data, which may be inconsistent; yet if we assume that `empid` defines the name and that `PhoneTable` contains an entry for every employee, the query could look as follows. The first part of the query combines the different records for one employee into one record; the left outer join then gets the corresponding e-mail. Note that the query is still not complete if there are employees that have an e-mail but not even a single phone number:

```
select *
from (select empid,
          max(fullname),
          max(case when type='Fix' then Number else NULL end) as fix,
          max(case when type='Mobile' then Number else NULL end) as Mobile
      from PhoneTable
      group by empid) phone
  left outer join EMailTable e on phone.empid=e.empid
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I just modified that.
And it works, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
select
e.FullName,
t1.Number as "Fix",
t2.Number as "Mobile",
em.Email
from
(
    select distinct
    EmpId,
    FullName
    from PhoneTable
) e
left join PhoneTable t1 on t1.EmpId = e.EmpId and t1.Type = 'Fix'
left join PhoneTable t2 on t2.EmpId = e.EmpId and t2.Type = 'Mobile'
left join EmailTable em on em.empID = e.EmpId
```

Answer (score 2):

my approach would be:

```
SELECT mail.FullName, phonefix.Number, phonemob.Number, mail.Email
  FROM EmailTable mail
FULL OUTER JOIN PhoneTable phonefix
 ON mail.empID = phonefix.empID
AND phonefix.Type = 'Fix'
FULL OUTER JOIN PhoneTable phonemob
 ON mail.empID = phonemob
AND phonemob.Type = 'Mobile'
```

of course if you have an Employee table. Start with the employee table and use left outer joins for linking to phone number and mail

Answer (score 1):

If you have fixed number of phone types, you can do this with one join per type, like this (assuming you have an employee table):

```
select e.EmpId, pt1.Number as "PtFix", pt2.Number as "PtMobile"
from Employee e
  left join PhoneTable pt1 
    on (e.EmpId = pt1.EmpId and pt1.Type = 'Fix')
  left join PhoneTable pt2 
    on (e.EmpId = PhoneTable.EmpId and pt2.Type = 'Mobile')
```

If there is a chance that you will introduce more phone types (eg. Office) you can aggregate them into an array or concatenate in mysql:

```
select e.EmpId, group_concat(pt.Number) as numbers
from Employee e
 left join PhoneTable pt 
   on (e.EmpId = pt.EmpId)
group by e.EmpId
```

Answer (score 0):

The table you call email table is the employee table really. It has exactly one entry per employee. So each employee has exactly one email address. As to phone numbers there can be zero or one phone number per type and employee I suppose. (And if there can be more, we just pick one.)

```
select e.fullname, p.fix, p.mobile, e.email
from emails
left join
(
  select 
    empid,
    max(case when type = 'Fix' then number end) as fix,
    max(case when type = 'Mobile' then number end) as mobile
  from phones
  group by empid
) p on p.empid = e.empid;
```