# Mysql display records even no result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables namely: listings and tags. These are sample records:

**Listings Table** 
[image]

**Tags Table** 
[image] 
This is my sample SQL query:

```
SELECT l.tag,
count(case when l.type = 'Consumer' then l.type = '' end) as consumer,
count(case when l.type = 'Supplier' then l.type = '' end) as supplier
                          FROM listings AS l
                          LEFT JOIN tags AS t
                          ON l.tag = t.tag
                          GROUP BY t.tag, l.type
```

But it displays like this:

[image]

I want something like this: 
[image]

Any ideas how to do it? I would gladly appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

**UPDATED:** Changed to:

```
SELECT l.tag,
count(case when l.type = 'Consumer' then l.type = '' end) as consumer,
count(case when l.type = 'Supplier' then l.type = '' end) as supplier
                          FROM listings AS l
                          LEFT JOIN tags AS t
                          ON l.tag = t.tag
                          GROUP BY t.tag, l.type
```

And this is the result: 
[image]

**OUTER** keyword seems working however I need to display still the AZ with 0 and 0 for Consumer and Supplier.

Comment: @Epodax mistakenly added php. Changed to SQL. ty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL how to do an outer join properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544462/sql-how-to-do-an-outer-join-properly)

Comment: you have `select distinct l.tag` and `group by t.tag`, *and* `l.tag = t.tag` join. so in effect you're asking it to show distinct units of a unique column Get rid of the distinct.

Comment: @Martin Already removed Distinct but still the same result.

Comment: Group by `l.tag` rather than `t.tag` I suspect this wont help but it keeps all the workings on the `listings` table rather than across both tables?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes remove l.type from group by and try to run the query.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad thanks for your reply. I removed l.type however, it just displays 4 records instead of 5 records. It should display AZ | 0 | 0

Comment: @Martin should be the same.

Comment: @LaposhasúAcsa I tried copying the sql from the link you added, however it doesn't display 0 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...........

```
SELECT t.tag,
count(case when l.type = 'Consumer' then l.type = '' end) as consumer,
count(case when l.type = 'Supplier' then l.type = '' end) as supplier
                          FROM listings AS l
                          RIGHT JOIN tags AS t
                          ON l.tag = t.tag
                          GROUP BY t.tag
```

Comment: Wow! This seems to be working on my end! RIGHT keyword is the right way to go!

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294778/mysql-quick-breakdown-of-the-types-of-joins

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using join for getting this when you have saved tag name itself instead of ids in listings table.

You can use this query

```
SELECT tag,
SUM(CASE when type = 'Consumer' then 1 else 0 END) AS Consumer,
SUM(CASE when type = 'Supplier' then 1 else 0 END) AS Supplier 
FROM `listings` group by tag
```

Comment: Thanks for this. There is a reason why I need to join the table (client's requirement) Your query seems to work however it doesn't display AZ with 0 and 0 for Consumer and Supplier